# append Selectbox value to textbox on body load

Tags: jquery

I am working on dynamic page.

Using {$pagetitle} smarty tag I get selectbox something like this.

```
<select name="page">
<option value="page1" title="Page1">Page1</option>
<option value="page2" title="Page2" selected>Page2</option>
<option value="page3" title="page3">Page3</option>
<option value="page4" title="Page4">Page4</option>
</select>
```

I can not have selectbox id as this is automatically generated through {smarty} tag

I want to append value of previously selected option to the textbox below on body load.

```
<input type="text" value"" id="pageno" />
```

How can I achieve this using JQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to query the select by name instead of id:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pageno').val($('select[name="page"]').val());
});
```

[See it in action at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DSkz4/).